# What are the limits of making a sorted fetchRequest with Core Data?

Tags: ios, cocoa, sorting, core-data, nsfetchrequest

---

**In short :**

Fetching entities and sorting them according to an `@property` which is not an `attribute` will cause a bug (with `NSDictionaryMapNode` involved) at the second run.

Is it normal or a bug ? Do you have any comment or help about that?

---

**In long :**

The situation is the following.

I have an `Entity` with two attributes `attribute1` and `attribute2`.

I have generated <sup>[1]</sup> a classe `Entity.m` and added a `@property` to it called `myProperty`. Hence, `myProperty` is a `@property` of my class `Entity.m` but not an attribute of the entity `Entity`. By the way, `myProperty` is `readonly` (let's say it is something like `attribute1` concatenated with `attribute2`.

Now, I do the following :

```
NSManagedObjectContext * myContext = ... ;
NSFetchRequest * myRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSSortDescriptor * mySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"myProperty"
                                                                    ascending:YES] ;
NSError *error ;

[myRequest setSortDescriptors:@[mySortDescriptor]] ;

NSArray * result  = [myContext executeFetchRequest:myRequest
                                             error:&error] ;
```

- The first time this code gets executed, I don't have any bug.
- The second time, I get the following bug :

  ```
  [<NSDictionaryMapNode 0x1020cf310> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myProperty.
  ```

I understand that the problem comes from `myProperty` not being an attribute of `Entity`. The aim of my post is to raise this situation and to know if you would have any comment about this situation.

[1] With mogenerator (https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).

Comment: What do you want to hear? You already found out that you can use *only persistent attributes* in a Core Data sort descriptor, there is *no way around it*. (It might not crash at the first time if all objects are loaded into memory.)

Comment: Hearing that "(It might not crash at the first time if all objects are loaded into memory.)" is interesting !

Comment: But that was pure speculation. You cannot use such a sort descriptor with the fetch request, even if it might not crash immediately. Of course you can fetch first and then sort the fetched array with any sort descriptor.

Comment: Ok, so imagine my situation, I am new to `Core Data`. I find a "bug", there is no reference on the web, the documentation does not say anything precise. It's good to hear : "Yes, we know, it's normal. You can't do that, you were right and everything is normal. There is no way out of this".

Comment: Then I did not understand your question correctly. But it is documented, Wain has given you the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known. You can't sort on anything that isn't persistent in the store. It should never work (to work the first time means that you don't have a MOC or something like that).

You should add a new attribute to the entity that is persistent. Do something like implement `willSave` or observe the dependent keys and use that trigger to update the value of the new attribute (`myProperty`).

---

See section `Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors` of [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html)

Comment: What I do is : 1) I fetch my request and 2) I sort it.

Comment: I've added a link to the docs. Note that you will eventually run into limits when you can't fetch all of the data because you don't have enough RAM.